# DateTimePicker.Value is returning an incorrect but consistent date

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

```
public void setRange(int which)       
{
    if (datelimitsset == 1)
    {
        if (startPicker.Value >= endPicker.Value && which == 1)
            // do stuff;
    }
 }
```

So this code simply does a datetimepicker.value to get the date. However it always returns the 1st of February when the maximum date is selected (The maximum date for my testing is 13/02/2012) Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: It is fine on in my vs2010. it is better to post source code.

Comment: You mean that one of the pickers has the wrong Value when you call this function? Are you sure you are not running other code that changes this value? Perhaps you've added an event handler that changes the Value if it is equal to MaxDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used:

`private void endPicker_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)`

event instead of:

`private void endPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

This event runs once a value is selected, not before; therefore it does not default to the first of the month.